# My solution seems too long - feedback welcome. Show $f(f^{-1}(S))=S \iff f$ is surjective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Below is my attempt at a standard exercise on basic set theory and functions.

There are **3 reasons for my request for feedback** on my solution:

1. I am self-teaching and that means I often think I am correct when I am not.
2. My solution seems much longer than any exercise I've done so far in Terence Tao's Analysis I which suggests I've missed something important.
3. I am not learning much from the many answers to the same exercise on this site. I want to check my thinking here, which is different from the thinking behind those answers there.

**(part of) Exercise 3.4.5** from Tao Analysis I 4ed

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$ . Show that $f(f^{-1}(S))=S$ for every $S \subseteq Y$ if and only if $f$ is surjective.

---

**My Solution**

**Strategy:** We need to prove both:

- **Part 1** $f(f^{-1}(S))=S \implies f$ is surjective.
- **Part 2** $f$ is surjective $\implies f(f^{-1}(S))=S$.

---

**Part 1 (proves contrapositive)**

Let's start with $f(f^{-1}(S))=S \implies f$ is surjective.

This is a statement of the form $A \implies B$, which we'll prove by showing the logically equivalent $\neg B \implies \neg A$.

So, let's consider that $f$ is not surjective. This means there exists an $s \in S$ for some $S \subseteq Y$, such that $f(x) \neq s$ for all $x \in X$.

The inverse image $f^{-1}(S)$ is, by definition, the set $\{x \in X : f(x) \in S\}$.

If we apply $f$ to the elements of this set, we obtain the set $\{f(x) \in S\}$. However, this set does not contain $s \in S$ because we have already defined it such that $f(x) \neq s$ for all $x \in X$.

Therefore, $f$ not surjective implies $f(f^{-1}(S)) \neq S$.

This is logically equivalent to $f(f^{-1}(S))=S \implies f$.

---

**Part 2**

Now let's show $f$ is surjective $\implies f(f^{-1}(S))=S$.

To do this we need to show that under the assumption $f$ is surjective, both of the following are true:

- $f(f^{-1}(S)) \subseteq S$
- $S \subseteq f(f^{-1}(S))$

Let's start with the first $f(f^{-1}(S)) \subseteq S$.

If $y \in f(f^{-1}(S))$ then $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in f^{-1}(S)$. By definition $f^{-1}(S)$ is the set $\{x \in X: f(x) \in S\}$.

So if $f(x) \in S$ then $y=f(x) \in S$. That is, $y \in f(f^{-1}(S)) \implies y \in S$. This is equivalent to $f(f^{-1}(S)) \subseteq S$. Note we didn't need $f$ to be surjective for this.

Now let's consider $S \subseteq f(f^{-1}(S))$.

Since $f$ is surjective, for every $y \in S$ there exists an $x \in f^{-1}(S)$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Here, $x \in f^{-1}(S)$ gives us $y = f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(S))$. Hence, $y \in S \implies y \in f(f^{-1}(S))$. This is equivalent to $S \subseteq f(f^{-1}(S))$.

Having shown both $f(f^{-1}(S)) \subseteq S$, and $S \subseteq f(f^{-1}(S))$, we can conclude $f(f^{-1}(S))=S$. This was under the assumption that $f$ is surjective, so we have $f$ is surjective $\implies f(f^{-1}(S))=S$.

Finally, having shown $f(f^{-1}(S))=S \implies f$ is surjective, and $f$ is surjective $\implies f(f^{-1}(S))=S$, we can say $f(f^{-1}(S))=S \iff f$ is surjective. $\square$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct, and it can be written concisely simply by eliminating  obvious statements and spaces. For example,

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$ . Show that $f(f^{-1}(S))=S$ for every $S \subseteq Y$ if and only if $f$ is surjective.

> $(\Longrightarrow)$ Assume $f(f^{-1}(S))=S$ for every $S \subseteq Y$, but suppose $f$ is not surjective, so that $\exists y $ s.t. there is no $x$ for which $f(x)=y$. Thus, for $S=\{y\}$, $f(f^{-1}(S))=S$ doesn't hold which gives a contradiction. Hence, $f$ must be surjective.
>
> $(\Longleftarrow)$ $f$ is surjective, hence, for every $y$, $X=f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a non-empty set for which $f(X)=\{y\}$ by definition. Hence, for any subset $\{y_i\}$ of $Y$,  $f(f^{-1}(\{y_i\})) = \displaystyle \bigcup_{y_i}  \;\{f(x) \;|\; x \in f^{-1}(\{y_i\} ) \} = \{ y_i \}  $

Comment: I asked a similar question and the critique there was that my strategy was wrong and my use of quantifiers imprecise/wrong. There was a suggestion that it is wrong here too. I'd appreciate your thoughts if you have time. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4851760/319008

Comment: @Penelope In your first part it is correct, in second you simply need to add - "Consider any $S \subseteq Y$".