# Show $f^{-1}(f(S))=S$ if and only if $f$ is injective. (stuck on how injectivity helps)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This question is about a standard exercise but my reasons for asking here are:

1. I am self-teaching and too often I think I understand something but in fact I don't.
2. The answers to the same problem on this site don't help with my specific question here.
3. My solution is long - so I suspect I have missed something important.

Problem, part of Exercise 3.4.5 Tao's Analysis I 4th Ed.

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$. Show $f^{-1}(f(S))=S$ for every $S \subseteq X$  if and only if $f$ is injective.

Because I want to isolate the root cause of any misunderstanding, I will write the solution in small steps.

---

**Strategy**

We need to prove both:

- **Part 1:** $f^{-1}(f(S))=S \implies f$ is injective.
- **Part 2:** $f$ is injective $\implies f^{-1}(f(S)) = S$.

---

**Part 1**

Let's start with $f^{-1}(f(S))=S \implies f$ is injective.

This is a statement of the form $A \implies B$, which we'll prove by showing the logically equivalent $\neg B \implies \neg A$.

So, let's consider $f$ is not injective. This means there could be an $x \in S$ and an $x' \in X \setminus S$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$.

**Question 1:** Is this a valid argument to start with? We could have $x \in S$ and $x' \in S$ such that $x \neq x$ but $f(x)=f(x')$.

The inverse image $f^{-1}(f(S))$ is, by definition, the set $\{x \in X: f(x) \in f(S)\}$.

Using our definitions of $x$ and $x'$, both qualify to be in this set as $f(x')=f(x) \in f(S)$.

However $x' \notin S$, which tells us $f^{-1}(f(S)) \neq S$.

Therefore, $f$ not injective implies $f^{-1}(f(S)) \neq S$.

This is logically equivalent to $f(f^{-1}(S))=S \implies f$ is injective.

**Question 2:** Even if this prove by contradiction is correct, is the the simplest way?

---

**Part 2**

Now let's show $f$ is injective $\implies f^{-1}(f(S))=S$.

To do this we need to show that under the assumption $f$ is injective, both of the following are true:

- $S \subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$
- $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$

Let's start with the first $S \subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$.

If $x \in S$, then $f(x) \in f(S)$.  By definition of inverse images, the set $f^{-1}(f(S))$ is $\{x \in X: f(x) \in f(S)\}$. Therefore $x$ is in this set, because it meets the membership criteria, $f(x) \in f(S)$.

So we have $x \in S \implies x \in f^{-1}(f(S))$. This is equivalent to $S \subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$. Note we didn't need injectivity to show this.

**Question 3:** Is this correct that we didn't need injectivity?

**Comment** I am least sure of the following.

Now let's consider $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$.

Consider an $x \in X$ that is a member of $f^{-1}(f(S))$. By definition of inverse images, this means $f(x) \in f(S)$.

Every $y \in f(S)$ has an $s \in S$ such that $f(s) = y$.

**Question 4:** I think this is wrong. This looks like surjectivity which is not relevant to this problem.

Suppose there is another $x' \in X \setminus S$ that is a member of $f^{-1}(f(S))$. That would require $f(x') \in f(S)$.

This means there is a $y \in f(S)$ where $f(x) =y$ and $f(x')=y$. This contradicts the injectivity of $f$. There can only be one $x \in X$ that maps to a given $y \in f(S)$ and since we know $s \in S$ is such that $f(s) \in f(S)$, then that $x$ must be in $S$.

Hence $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$.

Comment: How is $S$ related to $X$? Is $S$ supposed to be any subset of $X$? $\quad$ EG For question 1, if $ S = X$, then there is no $ x' \in X-S$. Likewise if $ S = \emptyset$, then there is no $ x \in X$.

Comment: In fact, suppose $f:X\to Y$. Then $f$ is injective iff $f^{-1}\circ f = \operatorname{id}_X$, and $f$ is surjective iff $f\circ f^{-1} = \operatorname{id}_Y$. The proofs are very straightforward.

Comment: @MPW That's playing a little too loose with notation, to the point where the "obvious" proofs are invalid.

Comment: @CalvinLin I've edited the question to state them missing fact that $S \subseteq X$.

Comment: @Penelope You have some typos and some seemingly contradictory statements.  I could fix the typos for you, but I wouldn't know what to do with the "seemingly contradictory statements".  For instance, in the first question, you seem to flip back and forth on whether $x' \in S$.  To answer your second question, in an attempt to fix the argument, suppose $f$ is not injective, so $f(x) = f(x')$ for some $x \neq x'$ and let $S = \{x\}$.  This way the argument will be clear.

Comment: Answer to Question 1: In part 1 you missed a crucial part of the hypothesis, namely: [$f^{-1}(f(S))=S$] for **every $S \subseteq X$**. Thus, $\neg A$ is: there exists **some** $S$ such that $f^{-1}(f(S))\ne S$. You are not yet given $S$ when you try to translate $\neg B$. You will have to construct it. So, your "This means there could be an $x \in S$ and an $x' \in X \setminus S$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$." makes no sense and your whole part 1 is completely flawed and not salvageable. For a correct way, see the many posts on this subject on this site. Don't encourage us to duplicate answer to FAQ

Comment: Follow up. If there is something you don't understand in "the answers to the same problem on this site", please point it explicitely. This will avoid duplicate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First.** Your statements of what you need to prove is imprecise.

For example, in one direction you say you need to prove
$$ f^{-1}(f(S))=S\implies f\text{ is injective.}$$
In fact, what you need to prove is
$$\Bigl( \forall S\subseteq X \bigl(f^{-1}(f(S))=S\bigr)\Bigr) \implies f\text{ is injective.}$$
That is, your assumption is not that $f^{-1}(f(S))=S$ for some fixed $S$; it is that for *every possible choice of $S$* you get equality. You want to use that to show that $f$ is one-to-one.

**Part 1.** Not being injective is equivalent to "there exist $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that $x_1\neq x_2$ *and* $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$." What is not correct is to talk about a specific $S$, or about $x$ and $x'$ being in or not in $S$. So your assertion that $f$ not injective means

> there could be an $x\in S$ and an $x'\in X\setminus S$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$

is at best imprecise and at worst just plain wrong. First, "there could be" doesn't say anything. Is there or isn't there? Second, that is not the negation of "for all subsets $S$ of $X$, $f^{-1}(f(S))=S$." Finally, *there is no $S$ yet*, so you can't talk about elements being in $S$ or not in $S$ until you name some $S$ you will consider.

So first you need to determine who $S$ is on the basis of $f$ not being injective. Because $f$ is not injective, you know there exists $x,x'\in X$ such that $x\neq x'$ and $f(x)=f(x')$. So now define $S$ to be $S=\{x\}$, and check that $f^{-1}f(S))\neq S$ *for this specific $S$*. This will prove that
$$\exists S\subseteq X( f^{-1}f(S))\neq S),$$
which is the negation of $\forall S\subseteq X(f^{-1}f(S))=S)$, i.e., what you need to establish to prove the contrapositive.

**Note that this is not a proof by contradiction.** It is a proof by contrapositive. Not the same thing.

For a direct proof: Let $x,x'\in X$ be such that $f(x)=f(x')$. Let $S=\{x\}$. Then we know that: (1) $S=f^{-1}(f(S))$ (by assumption), and that (2) $x'\in f^{-1}f(S))$ (since $f(x')=f(x)\in f(S)$). Therefore, $x'\in S=\{x\}$, so $x'=x$.

**Part 2.** Again, your statement is imprecise. What you actually want to show is that
$$f\text{ is injective}\implies \text{for every }S\subseteq X,\ f^{-1}(f(S))=S.$$

You are correct that the inclusion $S\subseteq f^{-1}f(S))$ always holds, regardless of injectivity, and your argument is correct.

For the second part you are correct as far as it goes up to Question 4. What you have not done yet is chase that to conclusion:

Suppose $x\in f^{-1}(f(S))$. That means $f(x)\in f(S)$. Therefore, there exists $y\in S$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Now, because $f$ is injective, this means that `fill-in-the-blank` and therefore we conclude that `something-about-x`.

You don't talk need about $x'\in X\setminus S$; it is irrelevant and confusing. Just use injectivity directly.

Comment: Artuto - thank you for the clarification that the proof needs to be $\forall S \subseteq X$. Does this same critique apply to my solution to another similar exercise, which was answered as 'correct' but now I am thinking I may have made the same mistake. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4849528/my-solution-seems-too-long-feedback-welcome-show-ff-1s-s-iff-f-is-s

Comment: @Penelope I didn't look very carefully, but at least the first part suffers from the same problem of using "some $S$" without specifying it.