# Gap in my proof of $f$ is injective $\implies f^{-1}(f(S))=S$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This question is about a gap in a proof I'm writing. I understand intuitively what the gap is - but can't find the correct or standard phrasing.

**Context**

The exercise is as follows (edited from ex 3.4.5 Terence Tao Analysis I 4th ed):

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$ .
> Show that $f^{-1}(f(S))=S$ for every $S \subseteq X$ if and only if $f$ is injective.

To do this we need to prove both:

- $f^{-1}(f(S))=S \implies f$ is injective.
- $f$ is injective $\implies f^{-1}(f(S))$.

The gap I am asking about is in the proof of the **second bullet point** only.

---

**My Incomplete Proof**

Let's show $f$ is injective $\implies f^{-1}(f(S))=S$.

To do this we need to show that under the assumption $f$ is injective, both of the following are true:

- $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$
- $S \subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$

**Part one:** Let's start with the first $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$.

By definition of inverse images, $f^{-1}(f(S))$ is the set $\{x \in X: f(x) \in f(S)\}$. If $x$ is a member of this set then $f(x) \in f(S)$.

⋮

⋮ (gap)

⋮

We have shown $x \in f^{-1}(f(S)) \implies x \in S$. That is, $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$.

**Part two:** Now let's consider $S \subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$.

By definition of inverse images, $f^{-1}(f(S))$ is the set $\{x \in X: f(x) \in f(S)\}$.

If $x \in S$, then $f(x) \in f(S)$, and so $x$ meets the membership conditions of this set.

That is, $x \in S \implies x \in f^{-1}(f(S))$. This is equivalent to $S \subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$.

Note that we don't need $f$ to be injective for this.

**Conclusion:** By showing both $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$ and $S \subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))$ under the assumption $f$ is injective, we have proven $f$ is injective $\implies f^{-1}(f(S))=S$. $\square$

---

**My Attempt to Complete the Gap**

By definition of inverse images, $f^{-1}(f(S))$ is the set $\{x \in X: f(x) \in f(S)\}$. If $x$ is a member of this set then $f(x) \in f(S)$.

For a given $y \in f(S)$, it must be the case that there is at least one $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. **(why is this? we've not said $f$ is surjective. is it because f(S) is an image not just a co-domain?)**

Without loss of generality, consider $f(x_1) = y$ and $f(x_2) = y$, where $x_1 \in S$ and $x_2 \in X$.

Because we have assumed $f$ is injective, by its definition, we have $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$.

There are two cases for $x = x_1 = x_2$.

1. $x \in S$
2. $x \in X \setminus S$

We know that $x \in S$ because $f(x) \in f(S)$. **(I'm not sure about this, what's the principle or axion or definition?)**

Thus, $x \notin X \setminus S$.

Thus we have shown $x \in f^{-1}(f(S)) \implies x \in S$. That is, $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$.

Comment: hi @Mike thanks for the link but sadly that doesn't help ( I was the OP for that post a while back and I had to go away and read Jay Cummings' book Proofs and come back! )

Comment: [Again](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4851760/742) you start by **mis-stating** what you need to prove. You do not need to prove $f^{-1}(f(S))=S\implies f$ injective. What you need to prove is $(\text{for every }S, f^{-1}(f(S))=S) \implies f$ injective. Not the same thing.

Comment: Hi I answered below.

Comment: hi @ArturoMagidin - please can you explain why it is not the same thing? The question states "for every ⊆ " so that is clear. In my proof I haven't assumed anything further about $S$ so I can't identify the problem you're alluding to. If I were attempting a proof by counter-example then I think that would be relevant?

Comment: The statements are different because the one you wrote is for a single $S$, the one I wrote is the correct one. It is not the same thing to say "every $x$ is green $\implies$ all numbers are green" and to write "$x$ is green $\implies$ all numbers are green." Note that I did not comment on your proof: what I said is that you made an error when you stated *what* you need to prove.  I did not read the rest because **I already answered this question for you**, but you decided to repost it anyway.

Comment: Clearly your previous answer didn't work for me, which is why I spent a month reading an entire book on proofs before coming back. I didn't repost the same question - this one focusses on a specific gap in my understanding. I don't want to waste your time so I recommend you let others comment on my questions.

Comment: You accepted the previous answer, which indicates it **did** "work for you". And I'm not stopping anyone from commenting or answering. I am pointing put that, a book later, you are still making the same threshold error by misstating what you need to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler way s to close the gap:

$f$ injective $\implies$ $f^{-1}f(S) \subseteq S$:

Proof: Let $x'$ be any element of the set $f^{-1}(f(S))$ $=$ $\{x; f(x) \in f(S)\}$. Then $f(x')$ is in $f(S)$, and thus by definition $f(x')$ is in $\{f(x); x \in S\}$, or equivalently, there is an $x \in S$ such that the equation $f(x')=f(x)$ holds. **But as $f$ is injective, the equation $f(x')=f(x)$ implies the equation $x' = x$.** So as $x$ is in $S$ and $x'=x$, it follows that $x'$ is in $S$ as well. Thus, any element $x'$ in the set $f^{-1}(f(S))$, is also in $S$, giving $f^{-1}(f(S)) \subseteq S$.

Comment: hi @Mike - the step I am not clear on is: ".. there is an ∈ such that the equation (′)=()." Why is this? I am probably overthinking it, and intuitively is makes sense, but I can't seem to connect this step to a definition or axiom?

Comment: If $f(x')$ is in $f(S)$, then $f(x') \in \{f(x); x \in S\}$, and so by definition there is an $x \in S$ such that $f(x')=f(x)$.